# Magento 2 - Import works but take toooo long - Any thoughts?

Tags: magento2

I have to import more than 100k products to my store, I have split the CSV files and I'm importing one by one (each one has about 1000 lines).

It is working, but for each file takes about 1 hour and 30 minutes.

Is there anything that I could do to speed it up?

Cloud Server:

- CPU 4 vCPUs
- RAM 4 GB
- System Disk 80 GB
- CentOS 7 (PVHVM)

Performance when importing: (You can see that the platform is not using all the resources in the server)

Ram 1.1 GB of 3.5 GB

CPUs 37%

Top 2 processes in execution and RAM usage while importing.

mysqld - 318.3 MB

httpd - 156.9 MB

Comment: It may depends on disk speed, or just switch to PHP7. Magento2 with PHP5 is really slooooooow

Comment: you can put manual index at the time of uploading and than rebuild indexes after uploading. but the time of manual index site will load slowly.

Comment: I have no option of manual index, only scheduled or on save. The platform in general is running pretty fast, only importing that is so slow.

Comment: Do you try to import products without images ?